# text wrapping in grid in view panel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, panel, word-wrap

I want to write a questionnaire. It will be in a tab. I would like three columns: Question Number, Question, Group Box. I will have 14 of these so everything has to have their own row. The text in column 2 will sometimes be long enough to wrap. I feel like I have tried every combination, but I either get really big font or really small font. I'd like to be able to resize the window. Whatever I have done most recently makes it resize vertically, but no horizontally. I am very much a beginner so I apologize in advance for spacing.

```
<Grid>
  <Label Name="ADCS" Content="ADCS" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="270*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="54*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Viewbox>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="stackPanel2">
                <Label Name="a1" Content="1." Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"   Margin="6" />
                <Label Name="lblADCS1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6" />
                <TextBlock 
                        Text="Do you like cheese?" TextWrapping = "WrapWithOverflow">
                </TextBlock>
                <GroupBox Header="ADCS1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Yes__1" />
                            <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="No__1" />
                            <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Maybe__1" />
                            <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Clear__1" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GroupBox>
                <Label Name="a2" Content="2." Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="6" />
                <Label Name="lblADCS2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="6">
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?" 
                        TextWrapping = "WrapWithOverflow">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Label>
                <GroupBox Header="ADCS2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Yes__2" />
                        <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="No__2" />
                        <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Maybe__2" />
                        <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Clear__2" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do that for 14 questions I suggest a data driven solution. Write a Question class and add 14 Question objects to a collection and databind the collection to a itemscontrol with some datatemplate.

Anyway, below is a grid that shows two questions with text wrapping.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="1" /> <!--Question Number-->
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="Do you like cheese?" /> <!--Question-->
    <GroupBox Header="ADCS1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"> <!--Group Box-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <RadioButton Content="A" />
            <RadioButton Content="B" />
            <RadioButton Content="C" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="1" /> <!--Question Number-->
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?" /> <!--Question-->
    <GroupBox Header="ADCS1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"> <!--Group Box-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <RadioButton Content="A" />
            <RadioButton Content="B" />
            <RadioButton Content="C" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: this worked like a charm -- and is a heck of a lot cleaner than mine! thanks so much

Comment: Even if this worked its a painful way to implement something 14 times over. Learn databinding, create a datatemplate and a Question class. The above way is to error prone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only doing the xaml and someone else is doing the code behind. At this point datatemplates are not a viable solution. Question: When we do move to datatemplates, do you know of good resource I can use to learn?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a bit your code:

- removed nested Viewbox, Grid and StackPanel, not sure why would you need them all together here
- made the StackPanel stretched
- added scrollviewer

see if it will work for you

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Name="ADCS" Content="ADCS" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6" />

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="stackPanel2" >
            <Label Name="a1" Content="1." Margin="6" />
            <Label Name="lblADCS1" Margin="6">
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="Do you like cheese?" TextWrapping = "WrapWithOverflow">
                </TextBlock>
            </Label>
            <GroupBox Header="ADCS1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Yes__1" />
                    <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="No__1" />
                    <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Maybe__1" />
                    <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Clear__1" />
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <Label Name="a2" Content="2." Margin="6" />
            <Label Name="lblADCS2" Margin="6">
                <TextBlock 
                            Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?" 
                            TextWrapping = "WrapWithOverflow">
                </TextBlock>
            </Label>
            <GroupBox Header="ADCS2" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Yes__2" />
                    <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="No__2" />
                    <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Maybe__2" />
                    <RadioButton Margin ="5" Name="Clear__2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: this solution, unfortunately, did not work as I needed. It gave me 6 rows down and no columns. I am quite sure that it was me who wasn't clear. I sincerely appreciate the time anyway. Thanks!