# Rotated label with image in grid

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have problem with rotated label. I want to center it in grid and make word in label not splitted. For now, like on the first list item it is splited to 2 lines.
I've tried `LineBreakMode` but this is not what I am looking for.
Also setting it to center of image is a challenge because when it comes to short words like "New". In this case, word is lowered because of margin. Is there any way to work with it?

```
<Grid
  Margin="10,0,10,0"
  ColumnSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="125"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image                                                      
      Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
      Margin="0,3,0,3"
      Source="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter }}"
      />
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding StatusDict}}"
              Margin="0,50,0,0"
              TextColor="White"
              FontSize="Micro"
              Rotation="270"
              />
        </StackLayout>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your label inside a stacklayout inside the grid, and then try to wrap the label.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

For more info, visit this link- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17488/xamarin-forms-label-wont-word-wrap-inside-a-grid 
Hope it helps.

Comment: you can also check this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344486/text-wrapping-in-grid-in-view-panel

Answer (score 0):

There's been quite a few issues around linebreaks with labels in xamarin in the past, plenty of threads on their forums discussing this kind of thing, but just out of interest have your tried simply setting the linebreakmode to not wrap the words. `LineBreakMode="NoWrap"`

```
<Grid Margin="10,0,10,0" ColumnSpacing="0">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="125"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,3,0,3" Source="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter }}"/>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="{Binding StatusDict}" Margin="0,50,0,0" TextColor="White" FontSize="Micro" Rotation="270" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
    </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

Links to the property info [HERE](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.LineBreakMode/), and link to the type info [HERE](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode/)

**It's worth bearing in mind** that you are explicitly setting the height of your rows, so you can't dynamically adjust the width of the label and expect the table to adjust, but if you wanted to always have the text on a single line, then you would need to look into adjusting the width of the label and height of the table row dynamically.